# How to add twitter button on my website?

Tags: button, twitter

how to add twitter button on my website?

Answer (score 3):

Please state more clear questions. What kind of button do you want?!

Check out the official Twitter developer sites that might offer what you want: http://dev.twitter.com/

The official "Tweet  Button" is here: http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton